# WebGL Overlay Google map: How to cast Shadows?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, three.js, webgl, webgloverlayview

How can I make the 3d objects that I load into the map using The WebGL overlay API, to cast shadows on the map tiles and on other loaded objects?

It seems to me that this is not supported yet( or this feature is removed) so is there any workaround?

Preferred WebGL framework: ThreeJs

Comment: Did some one get answer to this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A workaround with threeJS would be to put a thin box(it will not work with `planeGeometry`) on the ground that is completely transparent but receives the shadow. this can be achieved by [shadowMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial)

Note: this would only show the shadows from meshes added to the webgloverlay, not from the buildings on the map

Answer (score 0):

We do not have this option yet on google map , because overlay of map we get from "webgloverlayview" do not have receive shadow option.

I tried to create my own plane over google map and achieve the shadow
my plane opacity is very light like 0.3. I also added image below in of colorful plane to explain.

++
Please see @yosan_melese answer it prefect to use
[ShadowMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/ShadowMaterial)

here is example code

```
    import { Loader } from '@googlemaps/js-api-loader';
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import {FBXLoader} from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/FBXLoader.js';
    
    const apiOptions = {
      apiKey: 'A***********8',
      version: "beta",
      map_ids: [""]
    };
    let directionalLight = '';
    const mapOptions = {
      "tilt": 0,
      "heading": 0,
      "zoom": 18,
      "center": { lat: 33.57404, lng: 73.1637 },
      "mapId": "" ,
      "mapTypeId": 'roadmap'
    }
    /*
    roadmap: the default map that you usually see.
    satellite: satellite view of Google Maps and Google Earth, when available.
    hybrid: a mixture of roadmap and satellite view.
    terrain: a map based on terrain information, such as mountains and valleys.
    */
    async function initMap() {    
      const mapDiv = document.getElementById("map");
      const apiLoader = new Loader(apiOptions);
      await apiLoader.load();
      return new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);
    }
    
    let scene, renderer, camera, loader,loader1,controls;
    function initWebglOverlayView(map) {  
      
      const webglOverlayView = new google.maps.WebglOverlayView();
      
      webglOverlayView.onAdd = () => {   
        // set up the scene
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
    
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0xffffff, 0.75 ); // soft white light
        scene.add(ambientLight);
    
        directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
        directionalLight.position.x += (-90)
        directionalLight.position.y += 0
        directionalLight.position.z += 20
        directionalLight.castShadow = true
        const d = 100;
        directionalLight.shadow.camera.left = - d;
        directionalLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
        directionalLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
        directionalLight.shadow.camera.bottom = - d;
        scene.add(directionalLight);
        scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( directionalLight.shadow.camera ) );
    
    
        // FLOOR

/*
        const plane = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(2050, 2200, 300),
        new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xF3F4F5, opacity: 0.3, transparent: true}));
        plane.rotation.x = 0;
        plane.rotation.y = 0;
        plane.rotation.z = 0;
        plane.castShadow = true
        plane.receiveShadow = true
        scene.add(plane);
 */

//after yosan_melese answer i am using ShadowMaterial 

const geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 2000, 2000 );
geometry.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2 );

const material = new THREE.ShadowMaterial();
material.opacity = 0.5;

const plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
plane.rotation.x = 2;
plane.position.x = 0;
plane.position.y = 0;
plane.position.z = 0;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add( plane );   
    
        loader = new FBXLoader();
        loader.load( 'model/name_model.fbx', function ( object ) {
          object.scale.set( 1, 1, 1 );
          object.rotation.x = 1.480;
          object.rotation.y = 0.950;
          object.rotation.z = 0.070;
          object.castShadow = true;
          object.receiveShadow = true;
          object.name = "name_model"; 
          object.traverse( function ( child ) {
            if(child.isMesh ) {
              child.castShadow = true;
              child.receiveShadow = true;
            }
          });
          scene.add( object );
        });
      
      }
      
      webglOverlayView.onContextRestored = (gl) => {        
        // create the three.js renderer, using the
        // maps's WebGL rendering context.
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
          canvas: gl.canvas,
          context: gl,
          ...gl.getContextAttributes(),
        });
        renderer.autoClear = false;
        renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
        renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;
        renderer.receiveShadow = true;
        renderer.castShadow = true;
        
      }
    
      webglOverlayView.onDraw = (gl, coordinateTransformer) => {
        // update camera matrix to ensure the model is georeferenced correctly on the map     
        const matrix = coordinateTransformer.fromLatLngAltitude(mapOptions.center, 10);
        camera.projectionMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(matrix);
        webglOverlayView.requestRedraw();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        // always reset the GL state
        renderer.resetState();
    
      }
      webglOverlayView.setMap(map);
    
    }
    
    (async () => {        
      const map = await initMap();
      initWebglOverlayView(map);    
    })();
```

[image: opacity 0.3 plane over google map layer]

[image: with color plane for example]

after @yosan_melese code
[image]

Comment: try using shadowmaterial